# How can we disable ANSI/VT100 color codes added to ASP.NET Core logs

Tags: asp.net-core

We are hosting our ASP.NET Core services in Google Cloud, and the logs from Stack Driver always use ANSI/VT100 color codes, like this:

> `[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m`

Is there a way to tell the ASP.NET default logger to not use those codes?

(P.S.: I know we should move to structured logging, that's next)

Comment: Some discussion about this kind of thing here: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/428.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

based on [the github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/428),
set `ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS` env to `true` or add this to your `appsettings.json`:

```
"Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "DisableColors": true
    }
  }
```