# AWS Lambda & ASP.NET Core Logging

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 running in AWS Lambda with following setup:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Collection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWS.Logger.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2" Version="3.3.105.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup" Version="3.3.101" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.4" />
    ...
```

LambdaEntryPoint.cs:

```
    public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
    {
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                    config
                        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.AddAWSProvider();
        
                    // // When you need logging below set the minimum level. Otherwise the logging framework will default to Informational for external providers.
                    // logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                })

                .UseStartup<Startup>()
            ;
        }
    }
```

appSettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeLogLevel": true,
    "IncludeCategory": true,
    "IncludeNewline": true,
    "IncludeException": true,
    "IncludeEventId": false,
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
    }
  },
  
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Final result in AWS CloudWatch log looks like this:
[image]

There are invalid characters `[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:`  and also redundant lines. This is just a sample, but in case of exceptions with stack trace, logs are getting pretty long and are hard to read.

I am simply using Microsoft's ASP.NET Core default logger interface `ILogger<MySampleController>` and then calling

```
this.logger.LogInformation($"Mapping done, took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
```

What I am doing wrong? How to get log properly configured for AWS Cloudwatch?

Thanks!

Comment: They're terminal control characters (see [Why in rails CLI do I constantly see “←[32m.←[0m”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10293839), but so far I haven't figured out how to disable this _very_ annoying (air quotes) feature (end air quotes).

Comment: Wasted another half hour of my life to disable something that never should have been included as a default in the first place.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118756/how-can-we-disable-ansi-vt100-color-codes-added-to-asp-net-core-logs

Answer (score 1):

Effectively the same answer as for [How can we disable ANSI/VT100 color codes added to ASP.NET Core logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118756/how-can-we-disable-ansi-vt100-color-codes-added-to-asp-net-core-logs)

In your `appsettings.json` set the [ConsoleLogger.DisableColors Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.consolelogger.disablecolors?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1) to `true`

```json
    {
      "Logging": {
        "Console": {
          "DisableColors": true
        }
      }
    }
```